# Do the AMD Phenom-II chips have the TLB/errata 298 problem?

Tags: cpu, amd-phenom

I am looking at building a new PC and thought the AMD Phenom-II X4's were a great value for my needs.

I know that the older Phenom chips with "50" at the end of the model number were the fixed versions, but the numbers are a bit different on the Phenom-II's, and I couldn't find any information that cleared up rather or not the Phenom-II's had this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are free of this issue. TLB/errata 298 affected chips made in late 2007.  The Phenom II X4 was released in February, 2009.  The only chips which were affected were Phenom processors up to and including the "B2" and "BA" steppings.  The chips released from March 27, 2008 and later are clear of the bug, as are all Phenom II processors.  There's a bit more information in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Phenom).

Comment: No problem.  Good luck with your new system!  I just picked up a new Core i7-920, but it does indeed look like Phenom II X4's are worth consideration.  You may want to check out the following which compares Phenom II to Core i7-920:  http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/phenom-versus-i7,2360.html

Answer (score 1):

Phenom II still has the MSR values of the TLB fix in the CPU registers. Use the same Phenom TLB Disable tool (google it) with Crystal CPUID 32-bit. I can confirm that removing the fix DOES increase performance and lower CPU usage on my Phenom II X4 955BE

Sorry for the 2 year topic bump but I felt this was worth it.